# How to get a image path inside a html table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loops, html-table

I have a html table and I want to get all the content, I am having problems getting the img link in the fourth column.

This is the table

```
<table class="imagetable" border="1" id="tabla_ventana" style="display: table; overflow:     auto;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>TFs Name</th>
        <th>Accesion</th>
        <th>DB</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
        <th>Delete TF</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABF1</td>
        <td>M00015</td>
        <td>Transfac</td>
        <td>
            <img src="MatrixLogos/MAT0006.png" width="150" height="30">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img class="delete" src="images/Delete.png" style="cursor: pointer;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABF1</td>
        <td>M00197</td>
        <td>Transfac</td>
        <td>
            <img src="MatrixLogos/MAT0007.png" width="150" height="30">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img class="delete" src="images/Delete.png" style="cursor: pointer;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my JS, I define a variable so when I come to the image column I get this, because the text property doesn't work, but value and innerHTML either.

```
            var cellIndexMapping = {
                3: true
            };
            $("#tabla_ventana tr").each(function (rowIndex) {
                $(this).find("td").each(function (cellIndex) {
                    if (cellIndexMapping[cellIndex]) {
                        alert($(this).val()); //What i should put here
                    } else {
                        alert($(this).text());
                    }

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want...

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic line of code you need is `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute class in yours img like this 
**

```
<img class="imagen" src="MatrixLogos/MAT0006.png" width="150" height="30">
```

**

and in javascript with this code that should work "
**

```
$("#tabla_ventana img.imagen").each(function (){
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**
"